# Mysql php, Different tables for different project types

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am new to mysql database design. I am developing a small application for my use with php and mysql to handle my web development customers. The idea is to handle and manage all projects of customers.

My database as of now:
CUSTOMERS

- cus_id
- full_name
- email
- telephone
- date

PROJECTS

- project_id
- cus_id
- project_type
- date
- status

Now here the project type can be of different type, for example: web-design, logo design, SEO, ppc, brochure design and so on.

I need to manage each projects type separately. For eg: Web-design table can have diffrent table values as that of logo design..

My question is "Should I create a separate tables for each project type" If so what If I need to add extra project type in future. Add extra tables for each project type. Please help.

My project management would be something like this

```
Customer | Project type | details
---------------------------------
 abc xyz | web Design   | manage
 efg uvw | logo design  | manage
```

One customer can have more than one project like, webdesign , logo design etc. Each project has its own values for tables. Since this is the case, my question is should I create a separate table for each project tye, like table-webdesign, table-logodesign, table-brochuredesign etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overall it is probably ***best*** to have a `project_central` table with common attributes `id, title, type, percent_complete, date_started, status` and then create ancillary tables with specific fields as they pertain to the type of project so `web_projects` would have `project_central.id, site_name, server_language` and `logo_projects` could have `project_central.id, primary_colors, artist_name`

This will be far more scale-able in the future as you add on project types. It is also generally not advisable to purposely have nulls due to the row not being of correct project type.

**Easier view of first paragraph:**

- project_central

  - id (PK autoincrement)
  - title
  - type
  - percent_complete
  - date_started
  - status
- web_projects

  - project_central.id (FK)
  - site_name
  - server_language
- logo_projects

  - project_central.id (FK)
  - primary_colors
  - artist_name

Comment: Zeus, I didnt get what is ancillary tables? Sorry, if Iam wrong, Iam new to this. Is it same as creating separate table web_projects, logo_projects ?

Comment: In this context *Ancillary* means `related`. So you have the primary table which holds common data and then the related tables hold specific data for each project type. What is your primary language? There are many definitions on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question comes down to how different the data will be for each project type. If you expect to have significantly different columns of data, then you want to consider separate tables. However if most of the data is identical, one table should suffice.

For example if all projects will have hours-estimated, hours-spent, cost-estimate, etc and will only differ in say, logodesign has a quills-consumed column and webdesign has a sodas-consumed, it is often simpler to have a single table and NULL values for quills-consumed if it is a webdesign project.

Comment: Yes, chris, I agree with you. Here web design tables is different from other table, so in case if I create a separate table for each project, I dont have flexibility to add more project types in future, because tables get increased. However, I am targeting this app for web developers maintenance. What do you suggest?

Comment: There is no reason tables can't be added in the future as new project types are added. Since you say they carry significantly different data, they will need to have additional application layer code built anyway.